# Flex and Static Bend Radius of a Cable: Which one should be larger?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering

I am looking for a cable to be placed in a drag chain that is moved multiple times per minute. Therefore, the cable needs to have a flex lifetime of over 1M times. Since the space is also tight, the bend radius is of interest. However the datasheet mentions:

> - Flexing bending radius: $5\phi$
> - Static bending radius: $10\phi$

where $\phi$ is the diameter of the cable.

Shouldn't the flexing bending radius be larger than the static bending radius? I would expect that a cable flexing all the time would have more restrictions on the bending radius than one that never moves.

Comment: Can you link to the datashseet? It's possible that 'flexing' just means 'temporary' in this context? Your intuition is correct that flexing the cable back and forth will lower the lifespan of the cable, and bending should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: I edited your question replacing "O/" with $\phi$, which I assume is the actual symbol. Feel free to rollback my edit if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Wasabi the proper symbol is HTML &#x2300 or &#8960, not the greek letter phi, but those probably won't display in most browsers anyway. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miscellaneous_Technical

Comment: @JonathanRSwift, you can find the datasheet here: https://app.box.com/s/5ocvkzw1169xrsmtpwgzq86h5d070f3s (don't know if it is proper to post it like this, sorry if it is not)

Comment: @alephzero - I usually use the Nordic Alphabet character Ø or ø, because they’re super easy to type. The diameter symbol is part of Unicode, however, so should display on nearly every device: ⌀ The subtle difference is that it’s a true circle, where the “Nordic O” is slightly out-of-round.

Comment: @George - any reason you haven’t phoned up the company to ask this? That’d be my first step, but I’m in the UK so don’t want to pay for the international call!

Comment: @JonathanRSwift I did but they have a layered structure thus I can only get in contact with the sales rep, who is not very knowledgeable on this aspect. I have submitted a request via email, but haven't gotten an answer yet unfortunately.